# Altair Radial Chart in concatenated chart is "inverted"

Tags: python, altair

I've got an interactive Radial chart in Altair which I would like to use as part of a dashboard. On its own, it looks and works great. But when I put it into an hconcat or vconcat it goes from the radials extending out from the inner radius to extending INTO the inner radius as pictured below. Why?

Code Chunks Below and Chart Visualization:

```
#Single Radial Chart
highlight = alt.selection_multi(on='mouseover', name='highlight')

base = alt.Chart(rank_df).encode(
    theta = alt.Theta('count:Q', stack=True),
    radius = alt.Radius('count:Q', scale=alt.Scale(type='sqrt', zero=True, rangeMin=20)),
    order = alt.Order('count:Q')
).properties(
    title="",
    width = 300,
    height= 300
)

radial_1 = base.mark_arc(innerRadius=20, stroke='#fff').encode(
    color = alt.condition(
        highlight,
        alt.Color('GrantType:N', legend=None, sort=alt.EncodingSortField('GrantType', op='count', order='descending')),
        alt.value('lightgray')
    )
)
radial_2 = base.mark_text(radiusOffset=25).encode(
    text='count:Q', 
    size=alt.condition(
        highlight,
        alt.Size('count:Q', legend=None, scale=alt.Scale(type='log')),
        alt.value(0)
    ),
    color = alt.Color('GrantType:N', legend=None, sort=alt.EncodingSortField('GrantType', op='count', order='descending'))
)

funding_chart = (radial_1+radial_2).add_selection(highlight)
```

[image]

```
#Concatenated radial charts

comp_chart =  alt.hconcat(funding_chart, funding_chart).configure_view(
    strokeWidth=0
).configure_title(
    anchor='middle',
    fontSize=20
)
```

[image]

Comment: Good news, there's a workaround. Here's the answer I got on the github issue report if anyone else needs it:

https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/3017